# Open a link in current window and a new second window / tab

Tags: jquery

using jquery is it possible to do something to open a link in the current window and a second link in a second tab.

Before anyone asks it's not an annoying pop-under - it's something I've been asked to do it by the client for his companies system.

So

```
<a href='http://www.url1.com' data-secondwindow='http://www.url2.com'>Link</a>
```

I can't figure out how to get the second url to open via a window.open()

I don't need the second window to take focus

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick:

```
$("a").on("click", function () {
    window.open($(this).attr("data-secondwindow"), "_blank");
});
```

But note that browsers may block such dirty things...

---

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/4n5o93v7/)